# Python: The best way to get complex dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a dictionary in following format

> {'array': [[{u'unsigned': 15.0}], [{u'octet-string': 12.0}], [{u'octet-string': 12.0}], [{u'octet-string': 12.0}], [{u'octet-string': 45.0}], [{u'octet-string': 78.0}], [{u'octet-string': 89.0}], [{u'octet-string': 65.0}], [{u'octet-string': 352.0}], [{u'octet-string': 45.0}], [{u'octet-string': 12.0}], [{u'octet-string': 45.0}], [{u'octet-string': 78.0}], [{u'octet-string': 98.0}], [{u'octet-string': 352.0}], [{u'octet-string': 56.0}], [{u'octet-string': 89.0}], [{u'octet-string': 78.0}], [{u'octet-string': 45.0}], [{u'octet-string': 12.0}], [{u'octet-string': 23.0}], [{u'octet-string': 65.0}], [{u'octet-string': 65.0}], [{u'octet-string': 45.0}], [{u'octet-string': 78.0}], [{u'octet-string': 899.0}], [{u'octet-string': 8989.0}], [{u'octet-string': 6565.0}], [{u'octet-string': 323.0}], [{u'octet-string': 1211.0}]]}

what is the most effective way to get values of [15.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,45.0,,,,etc]

Comment: Why encapsulate your inner dictionaries with a list if they only have 1 value?

Comment: You have a dictionary, that contains a list of lists, each one containing a dictionary with one value and all those dictionaries use the same key for that value. This might be the worst storage model ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is making all kinds of assumptions about the data you're dealing with, but in the example you give you could do this:

```
[ a[0].values()[0] for a in d['array'] ]
```

... where `d` is your dictionary as above.  That evaluates to:

```
[15.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 45.0, 78.0, 89.0, 65.0, 352.0,
 45.0, 12.0, 45.0, 78.0, 98.0, 352.0, 56.0, 89.0, 78.0,
 45.0, 12.0, 23.0, 65.0, 65.0, 45.0, 78.0, 899.0, 8989.0,
 6565.0, 323.0, 1211.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[elem[0].values()[0] for elem in yourDict['array']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictionary `d`, you can use `d.values()` to get all the values in the dictionary.  For example:

```
d = {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0}
print(d.values())   # [1.0, 2.0]
```